# Xcode+Swift+XPC: How to start and deploy a Swift XPC target on MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xpc

**DISCLAIMER:** I am relatively new to MacOS/Xcode

I want to build a simple XPC Launch Agent in Swift (ie: in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`) but I could not find much documentation.
I started with Xcode XPC template but I do not know if it was a good idea for my Swift project.
I notice I should also have `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.demo.myservice.plist`

Versions:
- MacOS: 10.13.2
- Xcode: 9.2

Instruction to create the Xcode XPC Project:

1. File > New project
2. I chose the MacOS template: XPC
3. I create the bundle ‘com.demo.myservice’
4. It creates me an Objective-C project. So I delete all files (ie: `myserviceProtocol.h`, `myservice.h`, `myservice.m`, `main.m` and `Info.plist`
5. Create the files:

*myserviceProtocol.swift*

```
import Foundation

@objc(myserviceProtocol) protocol myserviceProtocol {
    func ping()
}
```

*myservice.swift*

```
import Foundation

class myservice : NSObject, myserviceProtocol {
    func ping() {
        print("ping")
    }
}
```

*main.swift*

```
import Foundation

class ServiceDelegate : NSObject, NSXPCListenerDelegate {
    func listener(_ listener: NSXPCListener, shouldAcceptNewConnection newConnection: NSXPCConnection) -> Bool {
        newConnection.exportedInterface = NSXPCInterface(with:myserviceProtocol.self)
        let exportedObject = myservice()
        newConnection.exportedObject = exportedObject
        newConnection.resume()
        return true
    }
}

// Create the listener and resume it:
//
let delegate = ServiceDelegate()
let listener = NSXPCListener.service()
listener.delegate = delegate;
listener.resume()
```

*Info.plist*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.demo.myservice</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>myservice</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

6. I build it:
   [image]
7. I copied `Info.plist` into ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ : `cp ~/Documents/myservice/myservice/Info.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.demo.myservice.plist`
   I retrieve my userid with `id -u`

And then I try to execute it from the command line (as it does not seem to do anything from Xcode):

```
sudo launchctl debug user/501/com.demo.myservice /Users/olivier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myservice-hbwefcgibyqbajguvblgcmxsnrmd/Build/Products/Debug/myservice.xpc
Configuration failed: 113: Could not find specified service
Could not find service "com.demo.myservice" in domain for uid: 501
```

I am not really sure of what I am doing. Was I right to use `XPC` template to create my swift XPC.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your Agent to provide an XPC service, you need to expose it as a Mach Service.

The way you are initialising your Listener is for an XPC Service (notice capital S), an XPC Service is a bundle that is part of your application's bundle, located inside the `Contents/XPCServices/` directory.

So in summary, you would have to:

1.) Create an Agent that exposes an XPC service via mach service. Your listener would look like:

```swift
let listener = NSXPCListener(machServiceName: "com.rderik.exampleXPC" )
```

2.) To consume your Agent's service you'll need to build the connection to that mach service.

```swift
let connection = NSXPCConnection(machServiceName: "com.rderik.exampleXPC")
```

I hope that helps.

If you want to read more, I wrote a tutorial on how to do that here:

https://rderik.com/blog/creating-a-launch-agent-that-provides-an-xpc-service-on-macos/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your goal is. If you just want a daemon that is managed by launchd, then you don't need XPC. Just create a daemon (probably with the Command Line Tool project template) and create a launchd plist configuration file (see `man launchd.plist`).

XPC is intended to communicate with a host app. The service binary should be embedded in your app bundle and launchd will launch it when your app tries to connect. You don't need to modify ~/Library/LaunchAgents for this.

Your app needs to setup an [NSXPCConnection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpcconnection) to connect to the XPCListener you created.

Something like:

```
let connection = NSXPCConnection(serviceName: "com.demo.myservice")
let interface = NSXPCInterface(with: myserviceProtocol.self)
connection.remoteObjectInterface = interface
connection.resume()
let proxy = connection.remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler {(error) in
            os_log("Connection Error: %{public}@", error.localizedDescription)
        } as! myserviceProtocol

// message proxy here to communicate with service
```

Both scenarios are covered in more detail in the [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html)